# integration without using $u$ substitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluation of Integration $\displaystyle \int \frac{4}{x+9}dx$ without using $u$ substitution.

What i try

$$4\int\frac{(x+9)-x}{x+9}dx=4\int dx-4\int\frac{x}{x+9}dx$$

How do I solve it without using $u$ substitution . Help me please.

I did not understand how one can able to solve without using $u$ substitution.

Comment: Are you allowed the "notice" that $\frac{d}{dx}\log(x+9)=\frac{1}{x+9}$?

Comment: Frankly, it's just silly not to use substitution. Without substitution of some sort, you can only evaluate a small handful of antiderivatives. For example, you couldn't evaluate $\int(1+x)^{1000}\;dx$

Comment: What is a $u$ substitution, as opposed to a good old substitution?

Comment: You may take two cases : $x <9$ or $x>9$. In the former case, the integrand in question will have the term $(1+x/9)^{-1}$. Write its Maclaurin series and then integrate. Similarly for the latter case, do the same for $(1+9/x)^{-1}$.

Comment: What you tried actually made this more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
$$ \int{\frac{a\cdot f'(x)}{f(x)}} = a\cdot \ln|f(x)|+C $$
Very useful to be aware of that.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use substitution, and to some degree I can foresee this being interpreted as such since its proof ultimately relies on it.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer: Why, just differentiate RHS(?)

Comment: I suppose that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Without using $u$-substitution, I can think of using that the integrand is a geometric progression in disguise. And further using the [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) of $\ln(1+x)$, we can get the antiderivative.

$$\int\frac{4/9}{1+x/9}\mathrm dx=\frac{4}{9}\int\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i}}{9^{i}}x^{i}\mathrm dx=4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i}}{9^{i+1}}\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}=4\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{9}\right)+\text{const.}$$